# grub2-common : Breaks: shim (< 13) but 0.9+1474479173.6c180c6-1ubuntu1 is installed

Tags: grub2, package-management, dependencies, woeusb

I get these errors after installing woeusb:

```
krish@krish-Inspiron-3558:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
[sudo] password for krish: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 grub2-common : Breaks: shim (< 13) but 0.9+1474479173.6c180c6-1ubuntu1 is installed
 shim-signed : Depends: shim (= 13-0ubuntu2) but 0.9+1474479173.6c180c6-1ubuntu1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
krish@krish-Inspiron-3558:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 grub2-common : Breaks: shim (< 13) but 0.9+1474479173.6c180c6-1ubuntu1 is installed
 shim-signed : Depends: shim (= 13-0ubuntu2) but 0.9+1474479173.6c180c6-1ubuntu1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

I also get:

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
  shim
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 257 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 440 kB of archives.
After this operation, 24.6 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main shim amd64 13-0ubuntu2 [440 kB]
Fetched 440 kB in 3s (119 kB/s) 
dpkg-deb: error: archive '/var/cache/apt/archives/shim_13-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb' has premature member 'control.tar.xz' before 'control.tar.gz', giving up
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/shim_13-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: None of the `shim-signed` versions listed (13-0ubuntu2 and 0.9+1474479173.6c180c6-1ubuntu1) are in the Ubuntu repositories. Either you are using some derivative of Ubuntu that is not supported here, or you are using some ancient unsupported release of Ubuntu.

Comment: @user535733, https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/shim appears to be the package, it's in Bionic still it seems (and [goes back to Trusty 14.04 LTS](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=shim&searchon=names)).

Comment: @pbhj look at the version numbers, and compare with what is (and has been) in the Ubuntu repos. The `rmadison` application (part of `devscripts` package) is handy for this kind of comparison work.

Comment: Ah, I was looking at the pastebin in the below comments, which are for Trusty with that same version of package as is in Bionic. Looks like it might be from the official [ppa on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/amd64/shim/).

Answer (score 0):

It's saying there is a problem with the `shim` package. This command:

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/shim_13-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

will remove the current version of the package.

Then purge any remnants of past installs of `shim`, update apt's caches and reinstall:

```
sudo apt purge shim; sudo apt update; sudo apt install shim
```

Comment: i got again error messages, Please see https://pastebin.com/mMv1vW5D

Comment: You could download it direct with your browser from https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/shim/download and then install with `sudo dpkg -i ./shim*` from the directory it was downloaded to. Works for me on 18.04.

Comment: now the error message is https://pastebin.com/kX2ncCv7

Comment: Ah, now this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpkg/+bug/1730627 suggests it's a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpkg/+bug/1730627/comments/19) with dpkg used by admin tools on Trusty, the packages are using xz compression but the Trusty `dpkg` can't handle it. Though, per that link, it seems it's fixed in the latest available Trusty dpkg. So what's your dpkg version can you update above [1.17.5ubuntu5.8](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpkg/1.17.5ubuntu5.8) which is when the fix was supposed to be in place.

Comment: pls see dpkg version https://pastebin.com/AvPm29R7

Comment: I solved it by using sudo aptitude remove woeusb then all the shim unmet dependencies over, then apt-get worked. Thanks for support.